# when I migrate from AndroidStudio version Chipmunk to AndroidStudio version Electric Eel and dolphin my app cannot be released sign

Tags: shrinkresources, android-studio-electric-eel

All xml files encoding are utf-8 and have `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

but when set shrinkResources false in build.gradle app is being built release without any problem  but I want shrinkResources to be true

please help me what is the problem

> Task :wallet:shrinkReleaseRes FAILED

Execution failed for task ':app:shrinkReleaseRes'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ShrinkProtoResourcesAction
> ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
> Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDnz9.png)

- I check all xml files they are correct
- I do clean and rebuild
- I do Invalidate Caches..

All xml files encoding are utf-8 and have `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

but when set shrinkResources false in build.gradle app is being built release without any problem  but I want shrinkResources to be true

please help me what is the problem

Comment: I'm facing same problem, did you find the solution? Please reply

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is still facing this issue, this might help.

I was facing this issue when using Gradle version 7.4.2, this got resolved when I updated Gradle version to 8.1.0. Apparently there is some issue with the previous Gradle version as mentioned in this thread.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/235863809?pli=1